# MSTest TeamCity - Use specific config files to run selenium using MS Tests

Tags: selenium, webdriver, teamcity, mstest

I have a requirement to use specific config files to run the selenium tests using TeamCity.

There are 4 environments and each enironment need to use 4 different config files.

Can anybody guide me how do i achieve this.

I am not sure where and what all changes are required to implement for this.

I am using TeamCity,MStest VS 2010,Selenium Webdriver.

I have different URL's for DEV,Continous Integration, Staging and Live. Is there a way to handle this different URL's while runnign the tests from TeamCity.? I am using the config file , I guess which can be used for this purpose. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Nant script to execute the tests one after the other.  Use XmlPoke to change the config file between test runs.